# Is this set of matrices a vector space?

Tags: matrices

I was wondering if this set of matrices is a vector space:

$Q=\begin{bmatrix}u&v\\ -\overline v&\overline u\end{bmatrix} Such\space that\space u,v\in\mathbb{C}$

1. is it a vector space on field $\mathbb{R}$?
2. is it a vector space on field $\mathbb{C}$?

I have tried to prove it wrong but it didn't work, so I think they are both vector spaces, I have tried to prove that it's closed to addition and multiplying by scalar, and it seems fine but i'm not sure with it, because from what I see, no matter what I do (addition or multiplying by a scalar) from both fields, the vectors $u,v$ will stay in the complex field.

It would be really appreciated if someone can approve my thinking if its right, or tell me whats wrong if its wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a vector space over $\mathbb R$, but not over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If you multiply by $i$, will the diagonal elements still be complex conjugates?

Comment: Thanks so much, I get it now